# How to add Azure AD Authentication to Existing ASP.NET MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, asp.net-identity

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC application using Visual Studio 2013. I followed this walk-through but it only concerns itself with a new greenfield project while selecting **Change Authentication** in project template: [Developing ASP.NET Apps with Windows Azure Active Directory](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory)

I am not interested in using OWIN and OpenID Connect Katana modules as these components have lots of issues so I am waiting for that technology to mature and render out all the current problems.

I aim is understand how to manually add all the components and configuration to my existing ASP.NET MVC application to achieve the same Azure AD authentication model in Rick Anderson's article.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The tooling in VS 2013 doesn't support adding this to an existing project.  At the bottom of the link you referenced in the **More Information** section is a deep dive article where I dissect the code and configuration that gets added.  So, you could use that as a reference to find the deltas and apply them to your project.

Now, Visual Studio 2015 offers us some hope in this scenario.  It's in preview of course, but you may give it a try.  In Solution Explorer, right click on your existing project and select the **Configure Azure AD Authentication** option.

[image]

Comment: I ended up using your article to add components piecemeal and it works!

Comment: Is there a way to handle an event like the OWIN equivalent SecurityTokenValidated because I want to add custom claims?

Comment: @puri, this is an old post, but towards the middle he talks about adding claims: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/22/group-amp-role-claims-use-the-graph-api-to-get-back-isinrole-and-authorize-in-windows-azure-ad-apps/  (the section on enrichment)

Comment: this shows an incompatible authentication configuration was found in this project.  My current project was under windows authentication. I tried removing windows authentication on the project in project properties and in web.config.

Answer (score 18):

In **Visual Studio 2017** the option to enable *Authentication with Azure Active Directory* is in Connected Services:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am not able to see the option Authentication with Azure Active Directory in VS 2019 Professional edition