# ASP.Net Azure OpenId integration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a project that uses Azure AD for SSO authentication. The azure side of the app has been configured and I was able to get SAML authentication working with the following code:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
    new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Wtrealm = realm,
        MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
    });
```

Configured this way the site works fine for web pages, but I also need to be able to have API calls that are called from a native client. I would like to use JWTs for authentication for the native apps and found documentation on how to set up a separate native application that serves up JWTs. I found instructions on using the **Add Connected Service** to add authentication to a blank site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581744/how-to-add-azure-ad-authentication-to-existing-asp-net-mvc-application) and it seemed to configure the site to use OpenId with the following code in my Startup.Auth.cs file being created:

```
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = Authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
    });
```

Unfortunately when I run the newly configured blank site I get the following error:

> IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys:
>   'Vxa8HJ8gNB1XfxYnIDHBl2YuSFc',  token:
>   '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","x5t":"Vxa8HJ8gNB1XfxYnIDHBl2YuSFc","kid":"Vxa8HJ8gNB1XfxYnIDHBl2YuSFc"}.{"aud":"c13f71a0-e658-4432-a61e-24140f2b5890","iss":"https://sts.windows.net/8948afa6-51e3-4041-8303-5688ba9c8135/","iat":1542235664,"nbf":1542235664,"exp":1542239564,"aio":"ASQA2/8JAAAA6+NtWgTWs4mQi7gcoqDJMWDjmQtgxL79oC3U112+XjI=",...

I've looked at the OpenId metadata for my app and key **Vxa8HJ8gNB1XfxYnIDHBl2YuSFc** isn't in there anywhere. Is there something simple that I have missed?

**Edit**

---

It looks like the authority that was configured was

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}
```

Comment: which authority did you use?

Comment: I added the authority above with a placeholder for our tenant id.

Comment: Do you want to try with https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0 ?

Comment: I tried that and still get the same result. By the way I had to add `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;` to the code to get the error to show why the signature validation was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a case with Microsoft and one of their developers helped discover that the problem was with OpenId and Enterprise applications. When I created a non-enterprise application (Web/API) I was able to get the web site to properly authenticate. I tested this by creating an enterprise app from scratch and comparing the browser behavior between the Web/API app and the Enterprise app. The problem only shows up for the enterprise app. I'm not sure what the difference is, but it is on Microsoft's side. Also, it only shows up for OpenId. I was able to get it working with SAML as I mentioned above. I'm not clear on what the distinction is between the Web/API app and the Enterprise app.